# iphone - distanceFromLocation accuracy

Tags: objective-c

I found this issue with distanceFromLocation function where the return value is not accurate. Please confirm if I did it wrongly or the function is buggy.

```
CLLocation *locA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:5.321008 longitude:100.290131];
CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:5.321008 longitude:100.290138];
CLLocationDistance distance = [locA distanceFromLocation:locB];
NSLog(@"distance: %f, locA: %f,%f, locB: %f,%f",distance,locA.coordinate.latitude,locA.coordinate.longitude,locB.coordinate.latitude,locB.coordinate.longitude);
```

The output is:

```
distance: 0.775644, locA: 5.321008,100.290131, locB: 5.321008,100.290138
```

Both locations are near and should be less than 10 meters. However, the function return larger distance. Checked with site such as http://jan.ucc.nau.edu/~cvm/latlongdist.html and the distance should be:

```
Distance between 5.321008N 100.290131E and 5.321008N 100.290138E is 0.0008 km
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is in meters if you convert it to kilemeters you get `0.000775 km` which is roughly the same. see [reference documentation from apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html) for more.

Answer (score 0):

This is a GPS issue with iPhones, not a coding problem.

Since iphones are meant primarily to do other things, the maker does not put in heavy duty GPS chips - like Sirf Star III, for example.  This would kill battery lifetime.  Instead the phone relies partially on another protocol mandated for cell phones since 9/11, which calculates distance from cell towers and does trilateration to get an approximate value.  Trilateration works in conjuction with the the weaker GPS chipset, if the chipset can find 4 satellites.  The result is that iphones often are of by more than 40 feet when using the GPS function.  BTW normal hand-held GPS units like Garmin (not surveryors differential GPS units) often are off by as much as 2-3 meters.

Look up differential GPS on Wikipedia to get more on this.